# COM Exception for client-side object called by Classic ASP page

Tags: asp-classic, com, vb6, lotus-notes, com-interop

I have tricky problem, which I'm struggling quite a bit with.

The current solution, consists of a **Classic ASP** site hosted on some Win2K3 server, that calls some **Client-side** DLL's on XP machines coded in **VB6**.

These client-side DLL's then again can call some other COM objects, in this particular case it calls IBM Louts Notes (Lotus Domino Objects 1.2).

Now for different reasons these **DLL's has to be converted to .NET (still x86)**, at this stage, this is the only change to be done. This works quite well except for one piece of code which throws an error.

```
COMException when calling the Lotus Notes COM object
```

**ASP script calling the DLL**

```
Set objLotus = CreateObject("OpenLotusNotes_FU_v2.clsMain")
sRet = objLotus.OpenLotus_mail()
```

**Client-side DLL**

```
Dim session As NotesSession = New NotesSession() 'works well
Dim objNotesWrkSp As Object
objNotesWrkSp = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Notes.NotesUIWorkspace")) 'crashes
```

**Exception**

```
Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {29131502-2EED-1069-BF5D-
00DD011186B7} failed due to the following error: 80080005 
Server execution failed (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80080005 (CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE)).
```

**When I try to run this code in console application on the same computer, it works**. So it has to be some permissions(?), I have tried changing basically everything I can think of.

Any help would be much appreciated!

**Updated 01.09.2014**

What I see is when I trigger the code from ASP, is that it creates a new process of *Notes* everytime, but only in the background, no UI what so ever. When I trigger the code from a console application, I get the Notes UI, which asks me for password, if I don't already have notes running.

I believe that I'm getting the Exception because it eventually times out.

Answer (score 0):

Have a read of [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adioltean/archive/2005/06/24/432519.aspx) , your dealing with an Out Of Process COM component which may not initialize properly for some reason.

Another possibility is that the COM threading model is not supported in a free threaded component which .NET is by default compiled with. You can compile you DLL with a STA attribute, but as far am I'm aware that only effects console applications. You might find some additional information in [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973800.aspx) from MS, if you have not already read it of course. Hope something there helps you solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I think you are onto something, though I'm not really able to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

Consult with your admins first, but for this scenario you can set no password for the ID the Lotus Notes uses.

Answer (score 0):

I did resolve this, so if anyone else would run in to this… 
First of all configure the “Notes Link” Component Service to run as a “The interactive user” and that the process owner has permissions in "Launch and Activation Permissions" and "Access permissions".

Then this should be possible

```
Dim objNotesWrkSp As Object
Dim objWorkspace As Type = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Notes.NotesUIWorkspace")
objNotesWrkSp = Activator.CreateInstance(objWorkspace)
```

As it turned out in this particular case I could only get it to work with late-binding, when I tried to this it just opened a conhost.exe process and then never responed:

```
Dim session as New NotesSession
session.Initialize()
```

Among other similar issues... So then I only used late-binding for all communication with Notes.

```
Dim mailServerPath, mailFile As String
objWorkspace.InvokeMember("OpenDatabase", Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, Nothing, objNotesWrkSp, New Object() {mailServerPath, mailFile})
```

And so on...